# C# find the adjacent elements of a sequence meeting a criteria

Tags: c#

so i have to write a program that fills an array with numbers and then find the adjacent even numbers like (2,4,6 etc) then class them in a sequence and then display the number of sequences and each sequence's elements 
EDIT : the numbers i'm referring to are the ones that have 0 as rest when dividing by 2 sorry for the misinterpretation

example

```
[1,2,2,3,4,6,9,3,2] it would display 2 sequences found and the contents are 2,2 and 4,6 (the last 2 was ignored because it isn't in a sequence)
```

here's what i did but i'm stuck with where to go with this

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows you'd like yo have ");
        int rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (rows > 20 || rows < 3)
            throw new ArgumentException("this isn't right");
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>(rows);
        List<int> D = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the " + i + "Element:");
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                D.Add(numbers[i]);

            }
```

i was thinking about having 2 separate lists 1 for the pair numbers and one for their indexes but that didn't work out

Comment: What should be returned for the input of `[1,2,2,2,3,4,6,4,8,9,3,2]`?

Comment: @mjwills 2 sequences one is 2,2,2 the other is 4,6,4,8

Comment: OK, so you are looking for adjacent even numbers?

Comment: yes @mjwills that is correct

Comment: @RufusL i'll change them rn

Comment: What does "class them in a sequence" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to loop through the numbers and, if the number is evenly divisible by 2, add it to a temporary list. If it's not evenly divisible by two, then check if your temporary list has more than one item in it, and if it does add that list to your result set. Then clear the temporary list if there's anything in it.

After the loop completes, do one more check on the temporary list and add it to the result set if necessary.

First, a helper function that gets a list of numbers from the user by allowing them to pass in a single entry of comma-separated values:

```
private static List<int> GetListOfNumbers()
{
    Console.Write("Enter a comma-separated list of numbers: ");

    return Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(',')
        .Where(item => item.Trim().All(char.IsNumber))
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToList();
}
```

Then the code to find even sets of numbers:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = GetListOfNumbers();
    var results = new List<List<int>>();
    var currentSet = new List<int>();

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            currentSet.Add(number);
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentSet.Count > 1)
            {
                results.Add(currentSet);
            }

            currentSet = new List<int>();
        }
    }

    if (currentSet.Count > 1)
    {
        results.Add(currentSet.ToList());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Results:");
    foreach (var setOfNumbers in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", setOfNumbers));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: exactly what i was looking for Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [`MoreLINQ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) then this is one approach:

```
var inputData = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2 };

var wasEven = false;
var results = inputData.Segment(z =>
        {
            var isEven = z % 2 == 0;
            var result = isEven != wasEven;
            wasEven = isEven;
            return result;
        })
    .Where(z => z.Count() > 1 && z.First() % 2 == 0)
    .SelectMany(z => z).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
```

The use of `Segment` is to break the input up into parts depending on whether the value has the same `even-ness` as the previous value in the input. Then `Count()` is used to only look at segments with more than one entry in them, and then `First` is used to ensure the segment contains evens (rather than odds). `SelectMany` and `ToList` then concatenates the segments back together into a single list.

Comment: i appreciate your effort but i can't use external libraries so only relying on doing it from scratch

Comment: @crystals It is very disappointing that you neglected to mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the built-in LINQ operators:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2 };

var results = 
    numbers
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            new[] { numbers.Take(1).ToList() }.ToList(),
            (a, n) =>
            {
                if (a.Last().Last() % 2 != n % 2)
                {
                    a.Add(new[] { n }.ToList());
                }
                else
                {
                    a.Last().Add(n);
                }
                return a;
            })
        .Where(x => x.Count > 1 && x.First() % 2 == 0)
        .ToList();
```

It gives `2, 2, 2` & `4, 6, 4, 8`.